# What appropriate boats exist between row and keel?

Tags: dnd-5e, equipment, vehicles

The [SRD](https://5thsrd.org/adventuring/equipment/mounts_and_vehicles/) (as well as the PHB and Saltmarsh) offers the following low-end water vehicles:

- Rowboat, a 10 foot vessel for 50gp.
- Keelboat, a 60 foot vessel for 3000gp.

There's a ridiculous gap between those two sizes & prices. What are some realistic medieval boats in that design space? Options in the ~200gp and ~800gp price ranges would be ideal.

Comment: Are you interested in "what I did and it worked" stuff or do you prefer something published?

Comment: either one, as long as there's some modicum of real boat lore behind it.

Comment: OK, I'll dig into my salt marsh stuff and find what I did. May take a bit of rummaging ...

Comment: Related: [question about basically the same for Pathfinder](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/70547/the-missing-link-in-pathfinder-boats/70551#70551).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A contributor at ENWorld posted a document with a few [extra ship types](https://www.enworld.org/resources/more-ships-of-the-sea.1527/) - caravel, cog, galleon, schooner and sloop. Its fan-made, no official, but its free and pretty good.

Comment: Unfortunately, when I [follow that thread](https://www.enworld.org/threads/more-ships-of-the-sea.659715) and reach the [file download](https://www.enworld.org/rpgdownloads.php?do=download&downloadid=1527), it's 404.

Comment: @Foo Bar follow the link in my post then click on the orange Go To Download link on the right hand side.

Comment: LOL, thanks. That button's UX is so "I am not part of the main content" that I didn't even look at it before.

Answer (score 1):

The 3.5E splatbook *[Stormwrack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stormwrack)* contains a complete superset of the boats in 5E. All of the PHB/GoS vessels are included and have the exact same GP costs, therefore its other boats should be usable exactly as-is, at least in terms of size, speed, & cost. The combat-specific stats are more complicated, but it should be possible to interpolate reasonable numbers.

It adds:

- Coracle, Dugout, Raft, Launch, & War Canoe at the low end,
- Pinnace, Barge, Cog, Dhow, Trireme, & Junk in the mid range,
- Elf Wingship, Ironclad, Greatship, & Theurgeme at the high end.

Comment: Do the stat blocks match the format of those in 5e, or will someone need to convert? I'm also not 100% sure that 3.5e economy is the same as 5e's, but i'll leave that to someone with the expertise (you?) to address.

Comment: Good point. Many of the stats don't line up exactly, so conversion will be needed.

Comment: I'm not sure how relevant this is, then.

Comment: Also a fair point. I'll work out a conversion formula and add the resulting stats to my answer.

Comment: Would probably be better for you to try it out before attempting that recommend untested homebrew.

Comment: The parts that matter most to me are size speed and cost, which can be used as-is. But I recognize that the other starts would add value  to the answer.